# Passing arguments to AndroidViewModel

Tags: android, persistence, viewmodel, android-room

I'm following the google [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#8) for Room persistence but i'm stuck, right now I have the tutorial all working fine but I need to expand it and be able to pass parameters to the `ViewModel` because what I need is to be able to submit different queries to the repo, and maybe i'm wrong but right now i'm doing it in the `ViewModel` which should be able to read his field and choose the right method to talk with the repo.

**WordViewModel:**

```
public class WordViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

 private WordRepository mRepository;

   private LiveData<List<Word>> mAllWords;
   public int mode = 0;       

   public WordViewModel (Application application) {
       super(application);
       mRepository = new WordRepository(application);
       if (mode==0)
         mAllWords = mRepository.getAllWords();
       else
         mAllWords = mRepository.getSomethingElse();
   }

   LiveData<List<Word>> getAllWords() { return mAllWords; }

   public void insert(Word word) { mRepository.insert(word); }
}
```

Then in the activity the triggers the model view we got this

```
mWordViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(WordViewModel.class);
mWordViewModel.mode=1; //MY ADDITION, not working
...
mWordViewModel.getAllWords().observe(this, new Observer<List<Word>>() {
   @Override
   public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<Word> words) {
       // Update the cached copy of the words in the adapter.
       adapter.setWords(words);
   }
});
...
```

Now the problem is that the field access and edit (the "mode" field) i've made is not working, it's like the field is getting resetted when the `ViewModel` is actually called and so it's always 0. What am i Missing? What is the easiest workaround considering that mode is just for explaining and eventually i'll need a lot of parameters (so creating various `ViewModel` is not an option)

Comment: make `mode` as static and change its value before initialize

Comment: @AbuYousuf what do you mean by "before initialize"? Only changing the field to static does nothing

Comment: add `WordViewModel.model = 1` before initialize `mWordViewModel`

Comment: @AbuYousuf it worked!

Answer (score 2):

I think you're running in to issues related to lifecycle of ViewModel itself and different variables etc you're using.  I'd recommend using something like `MediatorLiveData` for what you're trying to do...for example (this is in Kotlin btw as that's what I'm using for similar logic I have)

```
class WordViewModel : ViewModel() {
    .....

    val mode: MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData()

    val mAllWords = MediatorLiveData<List<Word>>().apply {
        this.addSource(mode) {
            if (mode.value == 0)
                this.value = mRepository.getAllWords()
            else 
                this.value = mRepository.getSomethingElse()        
        }
    }



    init {
        mode.value = 0
    }

    fun setMode(m: Int) {
        mode.value = m
    }

}
```

The code where I'm doing this here is https://github.com/joreilly/galway-bus-android/blob/master/base/src/main/java/com/surrus/galwaybus/ui/viewmodel/BusStopsViewModel.kt